# Dynamically retrieve variable name - is it possible?

Tags: isabelle

Is there a way to dynamically retrieve the name of variables in Isabelle/HOL?

I am trying to do something like this (in a simplified version):

```
consts sa :: "nat set"
       sb :: "nat set"

axiomatization  where
      sa_fin: "finite sa"
  and sb_fin: "finite sb"

definition expand :: "nat set set ⇒ string set" where 
  "expand S = {nameof(s)| s. s ∈ S}"
```

Basically, for the U below

```
definition U :: "nat set set" where "U = {sa, sb}"
```

the expand function will return {"sa", "sb"}. Is it possible at all within Isabelle/HOL?
TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, no. Your `expand` function cannot exist as a HOL function because you did not assume anywhere that `sa` and `sb` are distinct. If they are the same, there logically cannot be a function rhat returns `''sa''` for `sa` and `''sb''` for `sb`.

Of course, if you do know that `sa ≠ sb` you can easily define a function that does this manually, e.g. `nameof x = (if x = sa then ''sa'' else ''sb'')`. Generating a function like this automatically for a given set of constants is possible in Isabelle/ML. Finding all constants that were declared in a given theory should also be possible in Isabelle/ML.

But all of this seems a bit odd to me. I would wager that whatever you are trying to do here is probably possible in a more direct way. It's hard to say more without knowing what your exact use case is.

Comment: Thank you... That is exactly all I am trying to do, as odd as it seems. I need to get the names of a variable; I don't know upfront how many of these s I will have, or their names, all I know is that there will be a set of them. 

Let's call these s variable sorts. There will be a theory that defines this generic expand function. And an end user that will "instantiate" (aka define in their own theory) a set of these sorts with whatever they need (we assume all sorts are "nat sets" for simplification). And at one point, they'll need to expand the set of sorts "U".